# MariaDB high CPU usage even when idle

Tags: cpu-usage, mariadb

My MariaDB server is constantly using at least 30-40% CPU even when idle and no queries are being run.

What could possibly cause such a behavior? What should I check?

MariaDB Version: 10.3.22

Thanks!

Comment: It would help to know exactly what OS you are running, as well as screenshots or logs of  indicating the CPU being at 30-40%

Comment: ...and what is that DB used for ?

Comment: I’m running a linux VPS. I see in the process manager of cpanel that mysql is using 30-40% constant.

Comment: Please provide a sample of `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;`.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you will find something is in fact happening on the server. Enable general log and look what ends up in it.

One possible cause of this is a buggy database connection library on an application that keeps issuing

```
BEGIN;
```

or similar all over the place a few hundred times per second without doing anything else.